# Pthreads are being created with duplicate ID's

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am using threads to simulate a number of customers who want to book threater seats. Each customer (thread) is supposed to have a unique id and each thread receives some data through a struct (the id is included in that data inside the struct). The problem is that some threads have the same ID when I execute the code and I am wondering how is this happening since, in order for a thread to be created, another iteration of the for loop needs to happen and this way, the thread_id is updated with another value, before the struct is passed to the new thread and the next thread is created.

Can someone help me understand why duplicate values appear and how to fix that? Thanks!

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ThreadData threadData; //the struct which is used as input in the 
    // thread_transaction method, contains the id and other thread 
    //information
    pthread_t* thread_ids = (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * 
    n_cust);

    for(i = 0; i < n_cust; i++){
        threadData.thread_id = i;
        pthread_create(&thread_ids[i], NULL, &thread_transaction, (void *) 
        (&threadData));
    }

    for(j=0; j < n_cust; j++) {
        pthread_join(thread_ids[j], NULL);
    }
    printf("SEAT ARRANGEMENT: \n");
    for(y=0; y<Nseat;y++){
        printf("Seat %d / Costumer %d, ", y, threadData.seats_array[y]);
    }

    free(thread_ids);

    return 0;
  }


 void* thread_transaction(void* arg)
 {
   ThreadData* threadData = (ThreadData*) arg;
   pthread_mutex_lock(&id_mut); //i even tried mutex-locking the ID
   int id= threadData->thread_id;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&id_mut);
  .
  .
  .
   printf("Your reservation is completed successfully. Your transaction 
   number is %d ", id); //for 5 customers eg. it printed 4 0 4 2 2
 }
```

Comment: Each thread needs to be passed its own data — and since it is passed by pointer, that means you need a separate chunk of data for each thread (an array, or a separately allocated block of memory).  It you try sharing a variable, things go wrong.  This is one of the commonest issues with thread questions on SO; there should be a canonical question to which this can be made a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering how is this happening since, in order for a thread to
>   be created, another iteration of the for loop needs to happen and this
>   way, the thread_id is updated with another value, before the struct is
>   passed to the new thread and the next thread is created.

You have just about answered your own question.  Yes, on the next iteration of the loop, you update the thread_id of the same structure you presented to the previous thread.  So *what do you suppose happens if the previous thread hasn't read its ID value yet?*  Answer: it can read the value meant for the next thread instead of its own.

More generally, you have a data race because the `thread_id` member is shared between the main thread and the thread it has just created, they access it without proper synchronization,<sup>*</sup> and one of the accesses is a write.  A program that contains a data race has undefined behavior, so threads getting the wrong IDs is the least of your worries.

You could perhaps use a semaphore to provide the needed synchronization and ordering between the main thread and each new one, so that the main thread does not modify `threadData` prematurely or unsafely.  But I think it would be easier and more general to give each thread its own, separate  `ThreadData` object, whether dynamically allocated or from an ordinary array of them.

---

<sup>*</sup>Although the new thread protects its access with a mutex, that is not sufficient.  *All* accesses must be protected by the same mutex for that to provide proper synchronization.  Moreover, even that wouldn't ensure the needed relative ordering of the write and read.